# NSMenuItem -- include a simple graph

Tags: objective-c, macos, graph, nsmenuitem

Is there a way to make a `NSMenuItem` display a simple graph / chart (really, extremely simple, something like this, even without the grid would be fine : [image])?

It would be great if this could be done without using any additional libraries, but if there's no built-in way to do this, it'd be great to hear some suggestions of small libraries that could do this.

Answer (score 1):

You simply create a custom `NSView` which draws your graph and use [`-[NSMenuItem setView:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenuItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000265-SW1). The menu item then won't do any of its own drawing, but will display the assigned view in its frame.

Comment: Right, then I guess my question is how to draw the graph in the NSView?

Comment: A lot of info already available for that on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjc%5D+draw+graph, and have a look at core-plot: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/

Comment: I've searched before, and I saw some people mentioning Core Plot is not really ready for production apps yet, which is why I asked this question. Is Core Plot more stable now?

Comment: Sorry, not sure. Haven't used it.